# What is the number of zeros of the this polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, rouches-theorem

I wish to know the number of zeros of the polynomial $z^{10}-6z^7+3z^3+1$ in $|z|<1$.

Does it have something to do with Rouche's theorem?

Comment: Does it have something to do with Rouché's theorem? - Yes. ... ... Which form of Rouché's theorem do you have, and what have you attempted?

Comment: What is the exact number of zeros?

Comment: Hint: $1+3+1<6$

Comment: @Conrad Your hint is valued but still not understood.

Comment: Which term out of four is prevailing over the remaining terms at the boundary, i.e. for $|z|=1$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f=-6z^7$ and $g=z^{10}+3z^3+1$, and $K=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\vert z\vert <1\}$.
In $\partial K$ we have
$$\vert g\vert \leq \vert z^{10}+3\vert z^3\vert +1=5<6$$
while
$$\vert f\vert =6\vert z^7\vert=6$$
so by the Rouche's theorem we have that $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros in $K$, so the equation have $7$ zeros in $K$

Comment: I will never understand the reasons behind some people downvotes